# How do make safe query builder and prevent sql injection

Tags: mysql, database, go

This is my code:

```
type mysqlRepository struct {
    Conn *sql.DB
}

func (dbconn *mysqlRepository) GetAll(param map[string]string) (response []models.Subject, err error) {
    var result models.Subject

    c := 0
    q := `
        SELECT id, name, teacher, uuid
        FROM subject
    `

    for i, x := range param {
        if x != "" {
            if c > 0 {
                q += ` AND ` + i + ` = ` + x
            } else {
                q += ` WHERE ` + i + ` = ` + x
            }
            c++
        }
    }

    query, err := dbconn.Conn.Query(q)

    if err != nil {
        utils.QueryErrorException(err)
        return
    }

    defer query.Close()

    for query.Next() {
        errorScanningDataHistory := query.Scan(
            &result.ID,
            &result.Name,
            &result.Teacher,
            &result.UUID,
        )

        utils.QueryErrorException(errorScanningDataHistory)

        response = append(response, result)
    }

    return
}
```

I try using postman like this and run well: http://localhost/public/api/v1/subject?name=robert. It only show subject with robert as a teacher

But, If I inject sql command, it also works: http://localhost/public/api/v1/subject?name=robert OR 1=1. But, It return all data.

**How do I make more secure?**

Comment: Filter `i` through a map of known/allowed columns. Instead of concatenating `x` use the placeholder `?` and append `x` to a slice of arguments which you then pass to the query.

Comment: Sql injection occurs due to how you treat the input data provided to you from users. The best way to avoid it is, by constraining the input data types and what you want from the user. Therefore you should not allow user to input 'name' of type integer or 1=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

implement of @mkopriva 's comment

> Filter i through a map of known/allowed columns. Instead of
> concatenating x use the placeholder ? and append x to a slice of
> arguments which you then pass to the query

```golang
    safeFields := map[string]bool{"name": true}
    args := []interface{}{}
    where := "WHERE 1"
    for i, x := range param {
        if _, ok := safeFields[i]; ok && x != "" {
            where += fmt.Sprintf(" AND %s=?", i)
            args = append(args, x)
        }
    }

    query, err := dbconn.Conn.Query(q+where, args...)
```